# Angular 6 - Unit Testing Mat-Select

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular6

1: The mat-select has 4 values, 1,2,3,4.

The code below works good for the select. So I'd like to share if it helps the readers.

```
it('check the length of drop down', async () => {

    const trigger = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-select-trigger')).nativeElement;
    trigger.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const inquiryOptions = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.mat-option-text'));
        expect(inquiryOptions.length).toEqual(4);
    });
});
```

2: I need another test to verify the default value in the same
mat-select is 3 or not. When page loads the default value for the drop down is set to 3.

```
it('should validate the drop down value if it is set by default', async () => {

    const trigger = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-select-trigger')).nativeElement;
    trigger.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const inquiryOptions = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.mat-option-text'));
        const value = trigger.options[0].value;
        expect(value).toContain(3);
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This probably isn't helpful, but when I changed the value of a `mat-select` input, I couldn't see the DOM change until calling `fixture.detectChanges(); await fixture.whenStable(); fixture.detectChanges();` -- removing any of those 3 calls resulted in seeing the old value in the DOM on the next line.

Answer (score 14):

This one is worked for me in Angular 7

```js
    const debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    // open options dialog
    const matSelect = debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-select-trigger')).nativeElement;
    matSelect.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // select the first option (use queryAll if you want to chose an option)
    const matOption = debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-option')).nativeElement;
    matOption.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then( () => {
       const inputElement: HTMLElement = debugElement.query(By.css('.ask-input')).nativeElement;
       expect(inputElement.innerHTML.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
```

Comment: You have a typo: detechChanges -> detectChanges

Comment: how can i test the same in e2e?

Comment: You might be getting a false positive, because since you don't call done() in your whenStable function, you could have expect('fred').toBe('wilma') and your test would still pass. (I know because I tried it.)  Otherwise this answer worked for me as well.

Answer (score 5):

After some testing I found an answer (at least for my code) and hope, that this is helpful to you as well:

When I looked at the DOM, when the application is running, I noticed that the default value of the mat-select is inside this DOM structure:

```html
<mat-select>
    <div class="mat-select-trigger">
        <div class="mat-select-value">
            <span class="something">
                <span class="something">
                The value is here!
```

But in my case, I had a form builder in my .ts file and it was used in `ngOnInit()`. It seems that the normal `TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)` does not call `ngOnInit()`. So I had to do that in order to get the value. Otherwise there was just a placeholder `span`.

So, my final code looks like this:

```js
it('should validate the drop down value if it is set by default', async () => {

    const matSelectValueObject: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-select-value')).nativeElement;
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const innerSpan =
          matSelectValueObject.children[0].children[0];  // for getting the inner span

    expect(innerSpan.innerHTML).toEqual(3);              // or '3', I did not test that
});
```

By the way I'm using Angular 7, in case this matters.

Answer (score 5):

```
let loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);

const matSelect = await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatSelectHarness);
await matSelect[0].clickOptions();
const options = await matSelect[0].getOptions();
expect(await options[0].getText()).toMatch("");
expect(await options[1].getText()).toMatch('option1');
expect(await options[2].getText()).toMatch('option2');
```

Comment: `const options` didn't get populated until I added `await matSelect[0].open();`.

Comment: I didn't know about the Component Harnesses before this. Thanks! There's more information at https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/guides/using-component-harnesses.md and they encourage using this.

Answer (score 3):

Helper method for your page object to set the option by text:

```
public setMatSelectValue(element: HTMLElement, value: string): Promise<void> {
  // click on <mat-select>
  element.click();
  this.fixture.detectChanges();

  // options will be rendered inside OverlayContainer
  const overlay = TestBed.get(OverlayContainer).getContainerElement();

  // find an option by text value and click it
  const matOption = Array.from(overlay.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.mat-option span.mat-option-text'))
    .find(opt => opt.textContent.includes(value));
  matOption.click();

  this.fixture.detectChanges();
  return this.fixture.whenStable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const select = await loader.getAllHarnesses(MatSelectHarness);

//test to check there are how many mat selects
expect(select.length).toBe(1);

//open the mat select
await select[0].open();

//Get the options
const options = await select[0].getOptions();

//test to check option length
expect(options.length).toBe(1);

//test to check mat options
expect(await options[0].getText()).toBe('option 1');

expect(await options[1].getText()).toBe('option 2');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).